# How to Put the diffrent row value in td with comma

Tags: php, mysql

I am have MySQL query table

```
customer_id  name    service
1              a        sms
2              b       inbox
1              a       2-way
```

here the `customer_id 1` have two data ,when i write the query to retrieve the data from database and display it in table it only taking the first value `for example customer_id 1 having sms and inbox it only displaying inbox not displaying sms` ,but i want to display the both like this (sms,2-way),can any one gude how to do it.

my code:

```
<?php

                    $sql_selectcustomer = "SELECT customer_id,name FROM `customer` where reseller_id=1 ";

                    $result1 = mysql_query($sql_selectcustomer);

while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
{



    $customer_id=$rows['customer_id'];
    $customer_name=$rows['name'];

    $sql_service = "SELECT product FROM `products`  where customer_id='$customer_id'";
    //print $sql_service;
    $result_service = mysql_query($sql_service);
    while($row1=mysql_fetch_assoc($result_service))
{

    $product = $row1['product'];
    //print $product;
}

 echo '<tr>';

   echo ' <td class="edit name '.$rows["customer_id"].'">'.$customer_name.'</td>
            <td class="edit product '.$rows["customer_id"].'">'.$product.'</td>  


        </tr>';


}


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT customer_id,GROUP_CONCAT(service) as service 
FROM `products`  
WHERE customer_id='$customer_id' 
GROUP BY customerid
```

Sample result:

```
customer_id     service
-------------------------
1               sms,2-way
```